Is there an equivalent to tmux clear-history in vimterminal?
In tmux there is a command which clears any additional history that may have shown up in the buffer.
Does vim have a similar function for clearing out a vim terminal?

There is no command or vimscript function for that. The closest you can get with Vim's own stuff is adjusting :help 'termwinscroll' and that's not super close. This looks like something that could be added.
